# How to set TextAlignment property on a TextBox that is part of a Content of other element?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I have an element witch has TextBlock and TextBox in its Content property. I need to set TextAlignment for TextBox without interfering with the current style of the control, so I should make it work somehow with Setter Property and xaml.

Is this possible and how? I don't want to recreate Content with my own controls, or setting it through style, since style can be changed in runtime, and I want to preserve the styles as they are.

**Edit:** an example is DataForm. DataForm consists of several DataField elements. Each DataField consists of a Label and input control. Now, normally I could do this

```
<DataField Label="{Binding ...}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ...}" TextAlignment="Right" />
</DataField>
```

But if I do that, I will loose the style of the DataField, which I want to avoid. So, is there a way I can access this TextAlignment property of DataField, so I can set it to Right, but not for all of them, just the ones that I want (ex numeric ones). This is why it should be done on a particular instance of DataField.

So the task: set DataField Text to be aligned right, without interfering with its style, and do this for a particular DataField.

I hope now is more clear.

Comment: What kind of element you're adding this textblock and textboxes?

Comment: I am not adding anything, they already exist in the Content of this element. This is a 3rd party element. Imagine that you have a ListBoxItem, which has a TextBlock and TextBox inside its Content property. I need to set TextBox's TextAligned property without interfering with the style of the ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about create a specific TextBox Style?

```
<Style x:Key="AlignedTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Doing this way you can set it on xaml by the property "Style"

```
<TextBox Style="AlignedTextBoxStyle"></TextBox>
```

And if you are adding it dynamically you can also do this :

```
TextBox myTb = new TextBox();
myTb.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["AlignedTextBoxStyle"];
```

I think this is the best way to do that without interfering on your "ListBoxItem" style

Hope it helps

Comment: I am not following you. There is no TextBox declared in the xaml, so I cannot access it. I will update my question to explain with different example, to make it more clear.

Comment: Are you adding your textbox to the element in code-behind or another Class?

Comment: Please see edited question, I have given an example of DataField, if you know how to achive what I want with DataField, then I will accept the answer.